# Search inside documents with spotlight

Tags: spotlight, search

For years I had used spotlight to search inside of plain text files and other documents. As of late, Spotlight no longer searches inside documents it appears to only search their titles. Is there any easy fix to this? I'm running mojave (10.14)

Comment: Please update the post mentioning the version of macOS that you are running.

Comment: macOS Catalina does search the inside of files. Make sure your Privacy settings allow Spotlight to index files.

Answer (score 1):

An easy fix is to use [EasyFind](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/easyfind/id411673888?mt=12) to look for and inside files.  Easyfind is quick and versatile. You can select the type of files to look in if you want or just scan them all. Not as quick as Spotlight but more settings to control where you look. The app is free.